# How to limit act_as_votable gem for only one model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

I have a rails app where I have two tables Posts & Reviews, in Posts I have added a like system made from scratch, but in Reviews I would like to use the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem. I have added the gem and everything works fine, but because the User model for both Posts & Reviews is the same, the like system on Posts has stopped working, it is giving the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `vote_by' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/user.rb:64:in `add_like_to'
  app/controllers/api/likes_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

I think this error is happening because I have declared User as voter but in Posts that was not required.
Can you tell me if there is any way to declare `acts_as_voter` in `user.rb` only for one model, in my case Review?

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :google_oauth2]
  validates :username, presence: true
  validate :avatar_image_size

      has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :quotes, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "Post"
      has_many :liked_responses, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "Response"

      has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :bookmarked_posts, through: :bookmarks, source: :bookmarkable, source_type: "Post"
      has_many :bookmarked_responses, through: :bookmarks, source: :bookmarkable, source_type: "Response"

      has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :recipient_id

      after_destroy :clear_notifications
      after_commit :send_welcome_email, on: [:create]

      mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

      include UserFollowing
      include TagFollowing
      include SearchableUser
      include OmniauthableUser

      extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :username, use: [ :slugged, :finders ]

      def add_like_to(likeable_obj)
        likes.where(likeable: likeable_obj).first_or_create
      end

      def remove_like_from(likeable_obj)
        likes.where(likeable: likeable_obj).destroy_all
      end

      def liked?(likeable_obj)
        send("liked_#{downcased_class_name(likeable_obj)}_ids").include?(likeable_obj.id)
      end

      def add_bookmark_to(bookmarkable_obj)
        bookmarks.where(bookmarkable: bookmarkable_obj).first_or_create
      end

      def remove_bookmark_from(bookmarkable_obj)
        bookmarks.where(bookmarkable: bookmarkable_obj).destroy_all
      end

      def bookmarked?(bookmarkable_obj)
        send("bookmarked_#{downcased_class_name(bookmarkable_obj)}_ids").include?(bookmarkable_obj.id)
      end

      private

        # Validates the size on an uploaded image.
        def avatar_image_size
          if avatar.size > 5.megabytes
            errors.add(:avatar, "should be less than 5MB")
          end
        end

        # Returns a string of the objects class name downcased.
        def downcased_class_name(obj)
          obj.class.to_s.downcase
        end

        # Clears notifications where deleted user is the actor.
        def clear_notifications
          Notification.where(actor_id: self.id).destroy_all
        end

        def send_welcome_email
          WelcomeEmailJob.perform_later(self.id)
        end
    end
```

**likes_controller.rb**

```
# This controller serves as a parent controller for other likes_controllers. 
# Posts::LikesController for example.
# Child controller that inherit from this LikesController should implement 
# before_action :set_likeable, which sets @likeable.
class API::LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_likeable
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    current_user.add_like_to(@likeable)
    notify_author
    render json: { liked: true, count: @likeable.reload.likes.size, type: @likeable.class.to_s, id: @likeable.id }, status: 200
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.remove_like_from(@likeable)

    render json: { liked: false, count: @likeable.reload.likes.size, type: @likeable.class.to_s, id: @likeable.id }, status: 200
  end

  private

    def set_likeable
      raise NotImplementedError, "This #{self.class} cannot respond to 'set_likeable'"
    end

    def notify_author
      unless current_user?(@likeable.user)
        Notification.create(recipient: @likeable.user, actor: current_user, action: "liked your", notifiable: @likeable, is_new: true)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you are calling `vote_by` on a nil object in `user.rb` line 64. Can you show us your User class?

Comment: @FrançoisKoessler please have a look now, i have updated the question with user.rb

Comment: @Thatdude the error happen in the controller `app/controllers/api/likes_controlle` so you need to post your controller code.

Comment: @MoamenNaanou did that do check

Answer (score 0):

There's no call to `vote_by` in your `User` model so I'm not sure how you can get the error message pasted in your question.

Anyway you should probably implement the`set_likeable` method in your controller so that the `@likeable` instance variable passed as parameter to `current_user.add_like_to(@likeable)` is set.

I think this should fix your current problem.

Comment: when i delete acts_as_voter from user.rb it works fine but then my second like system that i got using acts_as_votable doesn't works